# Import library to logic app Javascript code step

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am having some issues trying to use hmac for authentication inside a logic app.

I tried to use a javascript step to create the string for authentication based on [this](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/) solution, but i don't know how to add references to external libraries. I am trying to avoid creating a new function app just to create the string for hmac.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't import external js libraries to inline code. For this requirement, you can just implement it in azure function and then use the azure function in your logic app. Or you can post a new idea on feedback [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to ask azure develop team to add this feature.